# How to update vue component if php artisan serve doesn't work?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

We made a little change on our Laravel project structuere. We made a file  'Larvel' inside the project. To make it work we changed the path in 'index.php' :

```
require __DIR__.'/laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

So the Command `php artisan serve` isn't working. Due to this problem our vue component isn't updating.

We are running it on local server using xmapp 
We want to keep the project structure as it is, and need a solution.

```
$npm run watch
$npm run watch --pull
$npm run dev
$npm run production
```

webpack.mix.js =>

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

> Main view file where all js & css files are linked in ->
>   master.blade.php

```
<script src="{{ asset('/') }}js/app.js"></script>
```

We expect if any changes we make in our vue component after running npm run watch then the update will show on our browser.

[public/js/app.js has moved in root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRySZ.png)

Comment: try to replace `<script src="{{ asset('/') }}js/app.js"></script>` with `<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script> `.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRySZ.png please see this picture. We've moved our js & css folder from public to root folder

Comment: Where are your artisan and composer.json file located? inside or outside the `laravel` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use version.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').version();


<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: It's not working. browser console error show: GET http://localhost/js/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)  (products:447)

Comment: Try <script src="{{ url(mix('js/app.js')) }}"></script>

Comment: it's connected but not show the update after i do any changes in vue component.

Comment: I've tried npm run watch , npm run watch-poll and also npm run dev but still not updating the vue component @Nikolay